# How to convert this hex string to unicode in java?

Tags: java, string, unicode, hex

I get below result from a web service:

```
 "\\x52\\x50\\x1F\\x1F\\x44\\x46\\x57\\x47"
```

I need to get the strings in unicode characters, which i think would be:

```
"\u0052\u0050\u001F\u001F\u0044\u0046\u0057\u0047"
```

i.e. "RPDFWG"

I cannot use `replace("\\x", "\u00");` because it says "\u00" is not a valid unicode

Comment: `replace("\\x", "\\u00")`

Comment: Does the result from the web service stick to characters in the ASCII range? Or can there be values of \x80 and greater, in which case character encoding is going to matter?

Comment: Do you really get the `\\x` from the web service, or is this just how you are representing it?

Comment: @guleryuz No. `\u` only works in the compiler.

Comment: http://www.javaonlineide.com/api/id/2c9fb47362e8f4e20162fb537669002b

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me:

```
try {
  String orig = "\\x52\\x50\\x1F\\x1F\\x44\\x46\\x57\\x47";
  byte[] bytes = new byte[orig.length() / 4];

  for (int i = 0; i < orig.length(); i += 4) {
    bytes[i / 4] = (byte) Integer.parseInt(orig.substring(i + 2, i + 4), 16);
  }

  System.out.println(new String(bytes, "UTF-8"));
}
catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

You might want to change the encoding to `ISO-8859-1`, or just plain `ASCII` -- I can't tell from your example what encoding is relevant here.

Comment: He put the `\\x` in quotes. I can't be sure the original poster is representing this correctly, but if you put that in quotes, the `\\x` should mean one actual slash character followed by the letter "x". I think it's reasonable for me to interpret the situation that way until the original poster says otherwise - and that reasonable assumption certainly isn't worthy of a down-vote.

Comment: @VicJordan: The above comment from me isn't directed toward you, it was a response to a now-deleted comment.